# WPF TreeView, Binding not working

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have `TreeView` that I am binding to List of My Data Class. Actually, I am using JSON data and create List from it. Also, I define a `DataTemplate` in `TreeView` to hold an `Image` and `TextBlock` in `StackPanel`. But when I run the project, it only show Text as I need, but not image. Then I transfer the `DataTemplate` from `TreeView.ItemTemplate` to `UserControl.Resources` with `DataType` declaration/define, and now it doesn't show anything. And I start getting

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IconImage' property not found on 'object' ''TVDataStructure' (HashCode=32882480)'. BindingExpression:Path=IconImage; DataItem='TVDataStructure' (HashCode=32882480); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
```

`TVDataStructure` has `IconImage` and `Header` named public properties, I believe that when I transfer `DataTemplate` to `TreeView.ItemTemplate` even then it doesn't bind properly but just show the name as my `DataStructure` has `Header`, which is same as `TreeViewItem's` Header object.

XAML Code

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="TVIDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type sotc:TVDataStructure}" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Name="IconHolder" Source="{Binding Path=IconImage}"/>
            <TextBlock Name="LabelHolder" Text="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="tvMain" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

In Code Behind I simply do this

```
 treeView_Expand(sender, e) {
   ...
   t.ItemsSource = ds;
 }
```

I simply call JSON string, run foreach on it, do some math and create List then assign (ds) to ItemsSource.

**Edit On Demand**

```
public class TVDataStructure
{
    public string Header;
    public object Tag;
    public ImageSource IconImage;
    public bool DoEvent = false;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Header;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show the TVDataStructure class?

Comment: Edit the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your public fields properties, for example

```
public string Header { get, set; }
```

That's it...

And, as a side info, the text is shown correctly in one of your versions because, when no template is found, WPF automatically creates a TextBlock, in which the string returned by `ToString()` is displayed.

Rebuild your code with explicitly setting the tree's `ItemTemplate` again.

Comment: doing as you suggest does the trick, but what is the difference between the two. I mean aren't they similar?

Comment: Basically yes, it's a WPF thing. WPF only recongnizes properties and no fields. I don't know why they force you to this, but because it is a good idea to always use public properties rather then public fields, I don't really mind.

Comment: I usually use Properties, but just got lazy this time. Thanks for your help. You make my day, after 6 hrs on this with 35C room temperature.

Comment: Oh dear, I wish we had 35C here ;) Good luck, glad I could help!

Comment: well I said Room Temperature, i.e. outside temperature is 45C I am all sweating mate. You better stay away from such heat. lol